# Profile page shows duplicates as "on hold" or "closed"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I just noticed that a question of mine that was closed as a duplicate shows on my profile as [closed] instead of [duplicate].

[image: closed]

I looked at other profiles and saw the same, duplicates were [on hold] or [closed]

Everywhere else they still show up as [duplicate]:

[image: duplicate]

Comment: Well... it is _closed_... as _duplicate_... so both are right ;)

Comment: @Oded right, but confusing. It's easy to get used to it. On the other hand, would it be hard to make it look consistent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug introduced by a denormalization optimization I made yesterday, it used to be on a closed question we had to go to the PostHistory for that Post and grab the last close history to see if it was a duplicate.  The other suffixes can be determined completely off existing fields.

To optimize this, a bit field was added to Posts but there were some queries not pulling that field, they were relying on a bool property (formerly of the same name) which did the PostHistory fetch.  Instead of going through history it simply says "false" when that happens now.

The query has been fixed in the next build and will display appropriately.