# Favorite questions are shown with "closed" or "on-hold" instead of "duplicate"

Tags: bug, profile-page, duplicate-questions, bookmarks

On the list of favorites in user profile, duplicate questions are shown with [on-hold] or [closed] instead of [duplicate].

[image: onhold]

(Actually, [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237824/) is a duplicate.)

This is confusing. Makes me wonder "what was wrong with that question?" and  go try to fix it to prevent deletion.

This is **different** from now-completed bug report [Profile page shows duplicates as "on hold" or "closed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197394/) because that one was a different section of user profile.